# copy cells from one sheet to another--where the target address is a string in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, copy, target

I have two sheets (call them ONE and TWO).  I want to copy a fixed range of cells from ONE to a target in TWO.  But the target address in TWO is a string value in a fixed cell in ONE.

For instance, ONE!C37 has a string value of "A1500".  And I want to copy cells from ONE!A32:ONE!W32 to TWO!A1500.  And, as the value of the string in cell ONE!C37 changes, so does the target destination in TWO.

Must be easy, but I can't see how to do this.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rich. Give this a try:

```
Sub movetosheet2()
Dim sheet_one_rng As Range:
Dim sheet_two_rng As Range:
Dim sheet_two_address As String:

Set sheet_one_rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
'Set the range from sheet 1 you'd like to copy onto sheet two

sheet_two_address = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value
'Supposing your location of "A1500" is stored in  cell D1 on Sheet1
'Note that the value of the D1 cell needs to be A1500:A1500
'and NOT just A1500
'You are essentially generating a string to pass into a range argument

'Set the destination range on Sheet 2 using your string

Set sheet_two_rng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(sheet_two_address)
'Use the Range.Copy method
sheet_one_rng.Copy Destination:=sheet_two_rng

End Sub
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: this fails in the same was as the code provided by user3598756 below.  see my explanation to him.  in summary, the source cells copied are from the target sheet, not the source sheet, and from the wrong column and wrong rows.

Comment: Thanks -- i think i know the problem. the cells A32:W32 are linked to and get their values from a vertical range of cells above. for instance cell A32 has the formula "=C4". So, i need to copy with a TRANSPOSE. The values i need to copy to the target are in a vertical set of cells (C4:C27). And they are to be copied to a horizontal set of cells. and I'd like to just copy cell values and not formatting

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out, based off of your comments to user3598756, glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
Sub CopyRange()

Dim RngSource           As Range
Dim RngDest             As Range
Dim DestString          As String


' set source range from sheet "ONE"
Set RngSource = Sheets("ONE").Range("A32:W32")

' read destination range from cell "A37" in sheet "ONE"
DestString = Sheets("ONE").Range("A37").Value

' set destination range from sheet "TWO"
Set RngDest = Sheets("TWO").Range(DestString)

' copy from Sheet "ONE" to Sheet "TWO"
RngSource.Copy Destination:=RngDest

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need one line:

```
Worksheets("ONE").Range("A32:W32").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TWO").Range(Worksheets("ONE").Range("C37").Value)
```

or, to use `With-End With` block and avoid some repetitions:

```
With Worksheets("ONE")
    .Range("A32:W32").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TWO").Range(.Range("C37").Value)
End With
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does some very weird transposition—and uses the wrong source cells. 
• The string in cell C37 is “A1877”, so it is supposed to copy cells A32:W32 to row 1877 in that other sheet.
• But what actually happens is that the wrong source cells are copied to that destination row.  The source cells copied are not from the current sheet (“ONE”), but are copied from the wrong place in the target sheet.  The actual source cells are from “TWO!C1848:1871” … 

So that code copies the wrong source cells from the wrong source sheet.  But the destination row is correct.

Comment: Thanks -- i think i know the problem.  the cells A32:W32 are linked to and get their values from a vertical range of cells above.  for instance cell A32 has the formula "=C4".  So, i need to copy with a TRANSPOSE.  The values i need to copy to the target are in a vertical set of cells (C4:C27).  And they are to be copied to a horizontal set of cells.  and I'd like to just copy cell values and not formatting.

Comment: So, given that my code does exactly what you asked for in your question, did you get through it with those new circumstances you wrote about in your comment?

Comment: thanks for your help, but my problem required me to mess around and finally use a xlPasteValues, Transpose=true solution.  i am now good, with code that separates the copy from the paste.  But, in any case, your rapid assistance was really appreciated.